# Why Is My Python Overtime Pay Function Wrong?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make an overtime pay calculator and can't see why my code is wrong:

```
def paycalc(hours):
    rate = 10
    reg_pay = hours * rate
    overtime = rate * 1.5
    over_pay = reg_pay + ((hours - 40) * (overtime))

    if hours <= 40:
        print(reg_pay)
    if hours > 40:
        print(over_pay)
```

When I run the function with `hours` <= 40, the function produces the correct output which is the product of rate and hours. However, when I put in `hours` > 40, the function produces greater than anticipated results.

For example, when you call the function for 40 hours, the function prints 400 which is what I expect. When I run the function with 41 hours, the function produces 425 instead of 415.

I'm unsure of why my `overtime` or `over_pay` variables could be causing these miscalculations.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to happen and what is wrong, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: Your issue is that you're trying to do overtime as time and a half, but you're adding the regular pay to the calculation as well. To fix it, change `overtime = rate * 1.5` to `overtime = rate * 0.5`. It's more of a mathematical error on your behalf than anything else.

Comment: @Brian this solves my issue, but it's unclear to me why overtime = 5 instead of overtime = 15 produces the desired results. Isn't 150% of 10 = 15?

Comment: Algebraically, it works like this: `over_pay = reg_pay + ((hours - 40) * (overtime))`, but we know that `reg_pay = hours * rate` so, when we substitute, `over_pay = hours * rate + ((hours - 40) * (overtime))`, so that means that each hour over 40 is being counted twice! Once in the `reg_pay` and a second time in the `((hours - 40) * (overtime))`!

Comment: I just now saw that! Thanks for helping to point that out. Let me see what I can do with this. I don't want to fudge with the incorrect rate to accommodate a correct result. I want the math to work.

Comment: For those interested, here is the updated and functioning code:

`def paycalc(hours):
    rate = 10
    reg_pay = hours * rate
    overtime = rate * 1.5
    over_pay = ((rate * 40) + (overtime * (hours - 40)))

    if hours <= 40:
        print(reg_pay)
    if hours > 40:
        print(over_pay)`